# Replace a text-converter dynamically

Tags: wpf

I have a textblock of a user-control which uses a converter to display figures. This converter gets loaded in a ResourceDictionary at the start of the application.
Now I'd like to exchange this converter with another one, to display a different format, depending on a parameter in the app-settings. Unfortunatley using just a trigger doesn't work. Is it possible to load a converter dynamically into the user-control, and put a reference on it from a textblock?

Edit: Here's my trigger attempt:

```
<TextBlock>
       <TextBlock.Style>
                <Style>
                     <Style.Triggers>
                      <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type mycontrol}, AncestorLevel=1}, Path=mode}" Value="0">
                            <Setter Property="TextBlock.Text" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type cg:Fader}, AncestorLevel=1}, Path=Figure, Converter={StaticResource ConverterA}}"/>
                      </DataTrigger>
                      <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type mycontrol}, AncestorLevel=1}, Path=mode}" Value="1">
                            <Setter Property="TextBlock.Text" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type cg:Fader}, AncestorLevel=1}, Path=Figure, Converter={StaticResource ConverterB}}"/>
                      </DataTrigger>
                      </Style.Triggers>
                 </Style>
         </TextBlock.Style>
</TextBlock>
```

Comment: Why trigger doesn't work. This should be achievable through style + triggers? So provide what you've already done.

Comment: okies, i'll edit my attempt.

Comment: If I apply this trigger (see edits) nothing gets displayed.

Comment: Have you checked whether values were bound properly (though converter)?

Comment: Oh no .. the Path hasn't been set to a dependency property. I created a propdp and now it's displayed correct. Thx for your hint :)
Path was a local variable .. that couldn't have worked :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why triggers are not working in your example is in bindings. Overall `Style` + `DataTriggers` are perfectly suitable for dynamic template selection.

Comment: Yes, I just forgot to put a path-reference to a dependencyProperty. It's not working if you are refering directly to variable.

Comment: yes ty. As I said in a comment above. I set the path to a dependencyProperty. Now it is working.